Exposing 28 ports on ECS on EC2
Is there a way to expose 28 ports on ECS on EC2 through a NLB?
I see there is a limit of 5 target groups to register on ECS but there is any workaround on this?
I need to declare 28 different ports with 28 different target groups.
If was thinking to some kind of lambda triggered by some events, to add and remove service private ip to the respective target group. Is there any other solution?

How many containers are in your ECS service, serving all those ports? Is it a single container that listens on all those ports? Or multiple containers?

What's the underlying use case for so many ports?
